# keyframes не определяется

Tags: css, css-animation, stylus, keyframes

```
@keyframes rot {
  0% {
    background-color: #000 !important;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #c0c0c0 !important;
  }
}

#telegramSiteHelperChatLabel
  animation-name rot
  animation-duration 2s
  animation-iteration-count infinite
```

Написано на `stylus` с `nib` префиксы оно ставит само.
В консоли хрома вижу это(св-ва нехарактерные хрому зачеркнуты, остальное валидно)

```
-webkit-animation-name: rot;
-moz-animation-name: rot;
-o-animation-name: rot;
-ms-animation-name: rot;
animation-name: rot;
-webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
-moz-animation-duration: 2s;
-o-animation-duration: 2s;
-ms-animation-duration: 2s;
animation-duration: 2s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-ms-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
```

Чуть ниже в панели keyframes вижу

```
0% {
}
main.css:1041
100% {
}
main.css:1044
```

На этих строках вроде валидные св-ва из вставки выше. Что интересно, если тот же самый код руками добавить в консоли все работает.

### Что не так? Всю голову сломал. Если надо, могу дать урл реального проекта.

Если убрать !important и сделать просто `background` все супер. **Почему?!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**То, что вы хотите сделать, не соответствует стандарту W3C.**

В [спецификации описывается](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/#keyframes), что ключевые кадры с `!important` игнорируются:

> The keyframe declaration block for a keyframe rule consists of
>   properties and values. .... In addition, keyframe rule declarations
>   qualified with !important are ignored.

А что собственно вы хотели сделать этим `important`? Анимация и так имеет приоритет еще больший, чем `important`:

```css
@keyframes rot {
  0% {
    background-color: #000;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #c0c0c0;
  }
}

div {
  background-color: red !important;
  animation: rot 2s infinite;
}
```

```html
<div>test</div>
```

Ну, кроме Firefox, который, кстати, в этом смысле соответствует [стандарту](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/#animations):

> Animations override all normal rules, but are overriden by !important
>   rules.

Comment: безумно извиняюсь, что принял только сейчас.